# Confusion regarding solar cells

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy

I am very confused by these two videos.

[This video mentions at 1 minute onwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKxrkht7CpY) that a solar cell has a PN junction.

[This video mentions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6KQiFctHmQ) N type solar panels and P type solar panels.

From that what I am able to understand, N type solar panels do not have a PN junction. It only has N type material while P type solar panels does not have a PN junction and it only has P type material.

From the first video, I understood that each and every solar panel has a PN junction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All [photovoltaic solar panels are PN junctions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell)  One side of the cell is a P type semiconductor while the other side is an N type semiconductor.

The P type and N type solar panels referred to in the second video also use PN junction solar cells - both types have PN junctions.

[The difference between the two lies in which side of the panel faces the light source.](https://chintglobal.com/blog/n-type-vs-p-type-solar-panels/)  In P type solar cells, the P semiconductor faces the light source.  In N type solar cells, the N semiconductor faces the light source.

Which side needs to face the light source depends on the semiconductor materials used in making the solar cells.

From what I have read, P type panels are more common and are prone to degradation over time, but they are better for use in space.  Much early development of solar cells was done for solar panels for space applications.  N type panels are turning out to be more efficient and less prone to degrading in applications here on Earth.

Answer (score 3):

All solar panels have PN junctions, N-and P-type ones. In fact, the PN junction is an essential component of a solar cell that allows it to convert light energy into electrical energy.

In an N-type solar panel, the semiconductor material is doped with impurities that create an **excess** of electrons, resulting in a material that has a negative charge or is negatively doped. The PN junction is formed by adding a thin layer of P-type semiconductor material on top of the N-type substrate.

In contrast, a P-type solar panel is created by doping semiconductor material with impurities that result in a **deficiency** of electrons, creating a material that has a positive charge or is positively doped. The PN junction is formed by adding a thin layer of N-type semiconductor material on top of the P-type substrate.

The basic working principle of both N-type and P-type solar panels is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please elaborate why that video and also some other videos on YT are referring to two types as N type and P type . Is there any difference in PN junction of N type solar panel and PN junction of P type solar panel ?

Comment: Ok, I added further description.

Comment: Once again,thanks for your time and consideration. But if you don't mind,can i accept answer of @JRE as i found that relatively more clear as that explictly mentions practical difference "In P type solar cells, the P semiconductor faces the light source. In N type solar cells, the N semiconductor faces the light source."

Comment: I don't mind ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is no different from ICs that may have a P-doped or N-doped bulk substrate. No matter which way the substrate is doped, you can add other layers of doping locally to create diodes, transistors, FET channels, and wires. The solar panels probably have a very different doling strength for the substrate than a typical bipolar IC, but someone who knows the process better could say more about that.